# requirejs not loading fbinstant library

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I try to load an external javascript library using requirejs. below is the code I use

```
requirejs.config({
paths: {
    FBInstant: 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbinstant.6.1'
},
shim : {
    'FBInstant': {
        exports: 'FBInstant'
    }
}});
```

but FBInstant is undefined when I try to access it.
If I add it like normal script it works

```
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbinstant.6.1.js"></script>
```

even FBInstant is undefined in the below code.

```
requirejs(['FBInstant'], function (FBInstant) {
// assign moment to global window object
    window.FBInstant = FBInstant;
});
```

I know that the js file is downloaded but somehow the FBInstant variable is not set. 
Does require only downloads the file and not execute it?
Any leads would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean that FBInstant is `null`? Is it not being set or being set to `null`?

Comment: It's undefined. It's not being set. I have made corrections. Sorry.

Comment: Could it be that since `FBInstant` is a asynchronous variable that `window.FBInstant` is not being set?